# IF yahoo finance api is not working what is the alternating way to fix this and display data by df.head()

Tags: python, pandas, dataset

```py
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import pandas_datareader as data
import yfinance 
start = '2010-01-01'
end = '2019-12-31'

df = data.DataReader('AAPL','yahoo', start, end)
df.head()
```

i am solving this by using yahoo but it is not working any other way through which i can get live dataset

Answer (score 0):

Following an example from the official documentation to query the Yahoo API returns the same error as your code does (see below). In the [source code](https://github.com/pydata/pandas-datareader/blob/main/pandas_datareader/yahoo/daily.py), error occurs in a method called `_read_one_data` of the `YahooDailyReader` class (function starts on line 142); **in other words, it's very likely that the package is broken and your code would work perfectly fine if it wasn't so.** Moreover, according to the information available on [pypi](https://pypi.org/project/pandas-datareader/), `pandas-datareader` has not been updated since almost 2 years!!

I suggest you to use another approach, e.g. the [yfinance package](https://pypi.org/project/yfinance/) which has been updated just a couple of weeks ago. Hope this helps!

Code from [pandas-datareader documentation](https://pandas-datareader.readthedocs.io/en/latest/remote_data.html#remote-data-yahoo):

```
import pandas_datareader.data as web
import pandas as pd

df = web.DataReader('GE', 'yahoo', start='2019-09-10', end='2019-10-09')

df.head()
```

Gives this error

```
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
TypeError                                 Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-1-f498884a1d78> in <cell line: 4>()
      2 import pandas as pd
      3 
----> 4 df = web.DataReader('GE', 'yahoo', start='2019-09-10', end='2019-10-09')
      5 
      6 df.head()

3 frames
/usr/local/lib/python3.10/dist-packages/pandas_datareader/yahoo/daily.py in _read_one_data(self, url, params)
    151         try:
    152             j = json.loads(re.search(ptrn, resp.text, re.DOTALL).group(1))
--> 153             data = j["context"]["dispatcher"]["stores"]["HistoricalPriceStore"]
    154         except KeyError:
    155             msg = "No data fetched for symbol {} using {}"

TypeError: string indices must be integers
```